# Codeigniter 4 form validation not working

Tags: forms, validation, url, codeigniter-4

I've followed the UserGuide, but it's not moving on to the Success page (+ it's not loading customised error messages).

Config/Validation.php:

```
    public $signup = [
        'username' => [
            'rules'  => 'required',
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'You must choose a Username.'
            ]
        ],
        'email'    => [
            'rules'  => 'required|valid_email',
            'errors' => [
                'valid_email' => 'Please check the Email field. It does not appear to be valid.'
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

My SignUp form View:

```
    <?php $validation->run($data, 'signup'); ?>

    <?= $validation->listErrors() ?>

    <?= form_open('form') ?>

    <h5>Username</h5>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

    <h5>Password</h5>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

    <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
    <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

    <h5>Email Address</h5>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

    </form>
```

And my Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Form extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form', 'url']);

        if (! $this->validate([]))
        {
            echo view('SignUp', [
                'validation' => $this->validator
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            echo view('Success');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm missing a piece of the puzzle - I just can't figure out which one!

Answer (score 0):

instead of typing your rules in **config/validation.php** i recommend you to type it in your controller

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Form extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form', 'url']);
        
        $rules = [
            'username' => [
                'rules'  => 'required',
                'errors' => [
                    'required' => 'You must choose a Username.'
                ]
            ],
            'email'    => [
                'rules'  => 'required|valid_email',
                'errors' => [
                    'valid_email' => 'Please check the Email field. It does not appear to be valid.'
                ]
            ],
        ];

        if (! $this->validate($rules))
        {
            $validation = $this->validator;
            return redirect()->to('/form/index')->with('validation',$validation);
        }
        else
        {
            echo view('Success');
        }
    }
}
```

and in your form view just delete this code

```
<?php $validation->run($data, 'signup'); ?>
```

it should be work.